# If the first index is greater than or equal to the second the result is an empty string

Tags: python, slice

In python slicing, 'If the first index is greater than or equal to the second the result is an empty string', then why the following operation return string?

```
>>> msg = 'HelloWorld'
>>> msg[4:-2]
'oWor'
```

Comment: because you have -2, the is reverse in a list!

Answer (score 5):

The quote you gave is either incorrect or incomplete:

If a negative number is used, it will be used as the reverse index on the file, meaning that `[4:-2]` is equivalent to `[4:len(msg)-2]` ie `[4:8]`

Note that if you use the reverse index to go further that the first index, you will indeed have an empty string.

```
msg[4:-8] # Equivalent to msg[4:1], by the same formula
>>> ''
```

Comment: I refer the quote from this link http://lola.hec.ulg.ac.be/pluginfile.php/45044/mod_resource/content/5/book2015-ch6.pdf

Comment: As far as I am aware, this quote holds True for Python - 3.x or even 2.x - only if you consider non-negative numbers...
On the plus side, you had the good reflex of testing the assertion for yourself :)

Comment: @veneth If the answer satisfies you, don't hesitate to accept using the checkbox :) It helps for people in the future who might have the same question as you !

Answer (score 0):

Negative numbers in python slicing effectively work backwards from positive. They start at the end of the string and move forward. So what your code says is give me a string starting at the 4th index and goes until 2 from the end.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes if negative they count from right. -1 is the last character. To access string from right index position we need to use - with index number. So for -2, it will be like take character till before l (for given example) and its total length must be 4. So it will be owor only.